# How same logout button will work for 3 different properties using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one logout button and it should work for 3 different logout functionalities `i.e- User logout,Logout from Facebook,Logout from Google`.I am explaining my code for 3 logout functionalities below.Please help me to write all inside one click event.

My logout button is given below.

```
<li><a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="fun_signout" id="sign_out">Sign Out</a></li>
```

> Local user logout:

```
protected void fun_signout(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Remove("User_Email");
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Response.Redirect("UserLogin.aspx");
        }
```

> Logout using Facebook:

```
protected void fun_signout(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FaceBookConnect.Logout(Request.QueryString["code"]);
        }
```

For google i am using JavaScript.So for that my Logout button should like below.

```
<li><a href="#" target='myIFrame' onClientClick="myIFrame.location='https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout'; startLogoutPolling();return false;" id="sign_out" >Sign Out</a></li>
```

And code for logout from google is explained below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startLogoutPolling() {
        window.location.href = "UserLogin.aspx";
        loggedIn = false;
    }
</script>
```

Here my requirement is i want to keep logout button same and implement all above functionalities .Please help me to do this.

Comment: Why don't you use 3 different buttons with same design but different implementation. Just hide and show the button depends on the login criteria?

Comment: @Chris: Yes,Its also very good idea but Is this possible by using same button ?

Comment: Probably you can create a delegate that can point to different method depends on the criteria of the login.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use a server sided ASP Control like the `asp:Button`. If you accept that it will do a PostBack (even on Google sign out) then you can do:

```
<asp:Button ID="bSignOut" runat="server" OnClick="bSignOut_Click" />
```

On the Page_Load, assign `CommandName` depending on your Login type:

```
this.bSignOut.CommandName = "Regular"; // or "Google" or "Facebook"
```

Then in your event you can determine what you do:

```
protected void bSignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button bSignOut = (Button)sender;
  if(bSignOut.CommandName.Equals("Regular"))
  {
        Session.Remove("User_Email");
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Response.Redirect("UserLogin.aspx");
  }
  else if(bSignOut.CommandName.Equals("Google"))
  {
        string script = "myIFrame.location='https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout'; startLogoutPolling();"
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GoogleSignOut", script, true);
  }
  else if(bSignOut.CommandName.Equals("Facebook"))
  {
        FaceBookConnect.Logout(Request.QueryString["code"]);
  }
}
```

If you don't want the PostBack on the Google signout you have no choice than creating a second button and toggle visibility or attaching the JavaScript (including `return false`) to the button on the `Page_Load`.

Comment: How initially browser will know which type of login this is ?

Comment: @satya This is your job. Once I enter your page, don't show any logout button. Once I logged in on anything you have to determine it on the PostBack. On "Regular" it should be easy. About "Google" and "Facebook", I never implemented those, so I can not tell you how exactly. This is somehow another type of question, though.